# When I try to create my Microsoft account , it says that someone has tried to sign up too many times , why?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am creating my Microsoft account (using *outlook*) for the first time on my PC.
When everything was done , it says:

[image]

**Someone has tried to sign up for a Microsoft account too many in one day--**
**Please try again tomorrow**

I have never opened store before or tried to sign up.
Now I have a few questions:
**1) Is my PC hacked?**
**2) Why it  is happening?**
**3) Is that a bug?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_rt-security/error-on-surface-rt-when-creating-a-microsoft/d604188f-338f-4d1d-8771-5ecf5a9cba6e

From that thread, I pulled the following relevant information:

> Creating 3 Microsoft Accounts on one device is what is permitted for 24 hours. You will have to try after 24 hours. Somebody would have created 3 accounts before you have tried creating one, so you were presented with that error message.

So there's your problem. Let's find a solution:

> It is SOLELY related to the PUBLIC IP address that you are creating the Microsoft account from.
>
> I just made my way through setting up 9 tablets today. I hit this roadblock after the 3rd one. So I started troubleshooting. When I disconnected from the internal WIFI and ran straight 4G, the others all finished fine.

This indicates that the problem isn't necessarily that your physical machine has tried too many times, it's that someone on your local network (who would therefore be sharing your outward-facing public IP address) tried too many times.

Now let's look at your actual questions and address them with this context in mind.

> 1) Is my PC hacked?

It seems unlikely that this is the case, but it's really hard to say without more details of the machine's history. If you bought it at a garage sale then it's all up in the air, but if you got it this morning from Best Buy an infection of some kind is far less likely.

There's also the possibility that your network is compromised in some way, and is controlling your computer or using your network to authorize other MS accounts. Again, without some context of what kind of network you're running and how many users and what security you have in place, it will be difficult for me to offer much insight. You should take a headcount of devices that are supposed to be on your network, verify that there aren't any machines accessing the network that you don't recognize, then log into your router settings and reset / change all of your passwords and security settings.

> 2) Why it is happening?

It's working as intended, you'll have to wait out the timer unfortunately. Nothing you can do is going to get around it because all of that verification takes place server-side.

> 3) Is that a bug?

Nah, man... it's a feature ;)

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** *(comment too long)*: If we have two machines, 1 and 2 (we will assume machine 1 is yours from the post, machine 2 is another computer that you may / may not own or have knowledge of), then this is the most likely scenario to have played out and landed you with this problem: You turned on machine 1, connected to network A (presumably your home network), and tried to make an MS account. In the 24 hours before you did that, either someone used machine 1 to attempt account creation or used machine 2 to access network A and then attempted account creation.

If you're on a public network (one you don't own or control), then there's nothing to worry about. People use public wi-fi for random stuff all the time, you probably just got unlucky and a bunch of people made MS accounts before you today. If, for example, you're on your own home network and you're the only authorized user that you are aware of (like you live alone and have never given out your wi-fi password)... well, then you have a potential problem with your PC or network being infected / otherwise compromised, someone breaking into your house to make random MS accounts ("MUWAHAHAHA"), or retrograde amnesia (cue Days of Our Lives theme music).

Comment: But I have created no account before , do you mean on my internet  IP Address?

Comment: @sudias Please review the edit to my answer, my response was too long for the comment character limit.